# An array returns the correct values but when called later returns all values as 'undefined'

Tags: arrays, node.js, express

I have a bunch a JSON files and my code reads the files and stores them into and array, When console logging the array i get the correct values and after but rendering a page, I console logged the array again the all of its values were 'undefined'.

```
let place = [];
let key, count = 0;

function Search(req, res){

  let fileName = getFileName(req, res);
  let emirate = req.body.emirate;
  let type = req.body.type;

  if(emirate == undefined || type == undefined){
    req.flash('error', 'Please fill in the form');
    res.redirect('/')

  }else{
    fs.readFile(`./places_files/${emirate}/${fileName}.json`, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        let rawData = JSON.parse(data);
        for(key in rawData.places){
          place[count] = rawData.places[count]
          count++;
        }
        console.log(place) // returns all of the values
        res.render('results', {
           places: place
        });
        console.log(place); // returns all values as undefined 
      }
    });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is this the code *verbatim*, with no changes? I wouldn't think that `res.render` would mutate

Comment: How can i redirect the page while passing "place" without res.render ?

Comment: **Security warning**: some malicious users might find ways to explore the server's file system, for example by inputting `{ emirate: '../../..', filename: 'passwords.json'}`, the server might inadvertently output password data. Think about it before moving to production!

Comment: I don't think it is a proper way to log the data after res.render where your control has already been gone to the  requested page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your res.render can mutate your values array.
To prevent this try to send copy of this array like this example:

```
res.render('results', {
   places: place.slice()
});
```

Another example:

```
res.render('results', {
   places: [...place]
});
```